# How should I encrypt the connection string in app.config?

Tags: c#, encryption

Which way is the best to encrypt the connstring in the app.config?

1. use `cryptography` to encrypt and decrypt, or
2. use `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\documents and settings\bob\projects\myproject"`, like recommended in [Protect App.Config file or Encrypt](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/3b5a1d1f-aa57-40d8-8607-fee0b2a8a6db).

Concerns:
1) If i use Crytography, everything works fine. Except that this code below will always be called each time when you run into  `using (leDataContext db = new leDataContext())`, which causes me to feel that it will slow down the system.

```
public partial class leDataContext
{
    public leDataContext()
        : base("")
       // : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leConnString"].ToString())
    {           
        string decrypted = Cryptography.Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leConnString"].ToString());
        base.Connection.ConnectionString = decrypted;
    }
}
```

2) If I use the method 2, it sounds good as it will automatically do the encryption. However, should I keep those encrypted `<CipherValue>rUmEA8h02uMZ5M4uEVtL+5M/UvPuyJ4UJz5d/P...</CipherValue>`  in my app.conf when I do publish using ClickOnce?

It is because those the method 2 can only be done at the client machine. So should I perform method 2 at client machine, then copy those encrypted code to a file, and each time when I want publish using clickOnce, then copy it manually back to the App.config before publishing, so that the client will update the right connstring?

Cryptography code:

```
  internal static string Encrypt(string sender, string key)
    {
        string text1;
        if (sender == null) sender = "";

        byte[] buffer4 = new byte[0];
        byte[] buffer1 = buffer4;
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[] { 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180 };

        try
        {
            buffer1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Substring(0, 8));
            DESCryptoServiceProvider provider1 = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] buffer3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sender);
            MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream1, provider1.CreateEncryptor(buffer1, buffer2), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            stream2.Write(buffer3, 0, buffer3.Length);
            stream2.FlushFinalBlock();
            text1 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream1.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            text1 = string.Empty;
        }
        return text1;
    }
```

Could you advice?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874614/c-connectionstring-encryption-questions. It might answer some of your questions.  Also, have you timed things to see if the first option really causes a slowdown?  I would think that making the connection to the server will be more expensive than decrypting the key.

Comment: i have tried the first option, i don see the system to get slow down but i just worry that it will when the data increase... just imagine u have to run that encryption code each time u initialize the datacontext()..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about the decryption code being called all the time, you could store it (either against the HttpContext.Items/Cache if you're worried about multiple calls on the same page, or a static if you're worried about it across all requests).

If you're going to put it in a static (note: this means the decrypted value is held in memory, which may be an issue, depending on exactly why you're encrypting it), I'd recommend using a static constructor to decrypt it to ensure the code runs only once and can't have any concurrent issues:

```
public partial class leDataContext
{
    private static DecryptedConnectionString;
    static leDataContext()
    {
        // This code is guaranteed to run only once, by the framework, before any calls to the instance constructor below.
        DecryptedConnectionString = Cryptography.Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leConnString"].ToString());
    }

    public leDataContext()
        : base("")
    {           
        base.Connection.ConnectionString = DecryptedConnectionString;
    }
}
```

There's also some built-in stuff for encrypting connection strings that might be a better choice:

#### Encrypting Configuration File Sections Using Protected Configuration

> ASP.NET 2.0 provides a new feature,
>   called protected configuration, that
>   enables you to encrypt sensitive
>   information in a configuration file.
>   Although primarily designed for
>   ASP.NET, protected configuration can
>   also be used to encrypt configuration
>   file sections in Windows applications.
>   For a detailed description of the new
>   protected configuration capabilities,
>   see [Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks you. Saving it to the memory is a good idea. :) You deserved a + 1.