# Obfuscate or Encrypt Wpf App.config

Tags: wpf, encryption, config

I currently have a C# Application that is a distribute, and that multiple people have. I was wondering which approach could I take to hide the app.config file (.exe.config) file that is produced after a build, So that the users cannot see my connectionstrings to my remote server. I read somewhere that If I encrypt the file, It can only be decrypted on the machine It was encrypted on, which means that It would not work for the other computers that the application is on, It would only work on my PC. Which approach could I take so that The config file can be hidden / obfuscated / encrypted, or anything to protect the config file, But without it being specific only to my computer, that can actually work for any one else who has the distributed version?
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I encrypt the connection string in app.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200805/how-should-i-encrypt-the-connection-string-in-app-config)

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever give a credential to someone if you don't want them to be able to use it. It really is that simple. You cannot both give a credential to and withhold a credential from the same entity. Whatever security checks you need to do, do them on your machine. That way, even someone who has the connection strings cannot bypass any security check you care about.

Comment: I know, I already do all the checks on my machine, I have integrated security on so there are no credentials, I just wanted to hide or encrypt some certain parts of the config file, for example such as the Membership providers which has all the Membership settings, or the connectionstrings, which shows my servers IP Address

Comment: Who exactly are you trying to hide them from? You can't hide an IP address from someone who has to connect to that address, right?

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean, Just thought It would be more secure to encrypt things such as connectionstrings and membership providers as its a distribute so you never know really, which is why I wanted to hide it, But also I see where your coming from.

Comment: Why hide something from someone authorized to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about exposing addresses of other machines you might want to consider putting these machine behind a router machine.

This way client machines and their users only know about the proxy and the remote machines would only have to be open to and trust the proxy.

Even if you encrypt the config file:

- the machine will need to decrypt the file to use the connection information so the secret is out any way
- using a network sniffer the user can always see to what machines his machine is connecting.