# Protect connectionStrings in app.config only works in local machine

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string

I'm trying to protect the connectionStrings in my app.config.

When the config has the connectionStrings unprotected, at the start I'm using this code to protect it:

```
try
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    ConnectionStringsSection connSection = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;
    if (connSection != null)
    {
        if (!connSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            connSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        }
        else
        {
            connSection.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        }
    }

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

Testing it in my own computer, works perfectly.

The problem comes when I execute the program in other computer (and the app.config was protected in mine). But if i paste the app.config unprotected (in the other computer), when the app is executed, protects it and after this it works normally.

I got the code in the microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

When there's a note saying:

> The connection string can only be decrypted on the computer on which
>   it was encrypted.

Obviously I don't want to have to distribute the .config unprotected.

How can I protect it on my computer and still have it work on other ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874614/c-sharp-connectionstring-encryption-questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# connectionString encryption questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874614/c-sharp-connectionstring-encryption-questions)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. No matter what kind of encryption you will use, the target computer has to decrypt it - this imply it has to know the method and/or the encryption key. Store the connection string as cleat text and provide DB credentials separately as you would do it usual.